# F# / Ionide in Visual Studio Code, max script length to FSI?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, fsi, ionide

I am having a problem sending F# scripts to F# Interactive using Ionide in Visual Studio Code.

I am using the "FSI: Send Selection" command using Alt+Enter.
This works fine for smaller scripts, but with script length exceeds a certain limit (approx 1.5kb), it no longer sends to FSI. There is no error shown in FSI, nothing happens. Reducing the selection size below this limit restores original behaviour, until it exceeds it again.

I've not found any clues online, and would appreciate any hints for how to resolve/investigate this. I've uninstalled and reinstalled Ionide & Visual Studio Code, without any effect.

Here is an example script that works, but adding even one more character takes it over the limit:

```
printfn "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
printfn "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
printfn "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
printfn "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
printfn "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
printfn "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
printfn "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
printfn "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
printfn "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
printfn "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
printfn "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
printfn "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
printfn "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
printfn "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
printfn "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
printfn "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
printfn "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
printfn "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
printfn "12345678901234567890"
```

Comment: It works fine for me, even with much more than this.

Comment: Thanks asibahi, I feared this would be so or the internet would be full of people complaining :-) Still, good to be sure, thanks for letting me know. Fingers crossed someone might have an idea what could cause my issue, as I am flummoxed.

Comment: This is also reported here https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-fsharp/issues/199. But works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks Antti, knowing I'm not the only one gives me some hope!